# glassfish Rest WEB9031 Exception

Tags: rest, glassfish-3

I have a Rest Web service deployed on Glassfish 3.1.2. I sporadically get a particular exception on it.

```
[#|2012-12-20T10:48:33.796+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[Jersey REST Service]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [java.util.TimeZone], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped (through reference chain: spreadsheet.Exceldatalist["globalContext"]->spreadsheet.GlobalContext["dateOfCreation"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:218)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:183)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.SerializerBase.wrapAndThrow(SerializerBase.java:140)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:158)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:610)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1604)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo(JacksonJsonProvider.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.writeTo(JacksonProviderProxy.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [java.util.TimeZone], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1401)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass._addMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:620)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:408)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.classWithCreators(BasicClassIntrospector.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.collectProperties(BasicClassIntrospector.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:96)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:16)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.introspect(SerializationConfig.java:974)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:251)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:782)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:735)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:344)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.PropertySerializerMap.findAndAddSerializer(PropertySerializerMap.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._findAndAddDynamic(BeanPropertyWriter.java:463)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:441)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
```

My Web service marshals an xml on the server after processing. The xml contains a time set in a tag

```
GregorianCalendar gc = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar
            .getInstance();
globalContextObj.setDateOfCreation(DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
                        .newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc));
```

The jaxb xml object is private member var of the class, changing the access modifier from static to none is not affecting the exception. I read about the `WEB9031` exception that it is caused by the classloader not being able to load the TimeZone class library. Glassfish documentation suggests that while deploying we must mention the common libraries in the console. But I have no common libraries. I think that the java.util.timezone class mentioned in the exception is getting unloaded or something like that.

If anyone has any idea to resolve this please let me know!!

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle the cause and solution of [WEB9031](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1755/gjkmu/index.html) is:

> Cause:
> This problem usually indicates that the classloader of a web application was cached, and an attempt is being made to have it load resources even though the web application with which the classloader used to be associated has already been undeployed
>
> Solution:
> Make sure that the classloader associated with your web application is not cached and used beyond the lifetime of your web application

Since your problem appears sporadic, it sounds like it could be a caching issue. Personally though, I think it should be unnecessary to ask a Glassfish user to place a standard Java class (`java.util.TimeZone`) on Glassfish's classpath when Glassfish itself is a server for Java applications! Suggestions to mention the class containing `java.util.TimeZone` when starting the domain from the console might only work because it'll add the library back to the classpath.

Try stopping and starting the domain again to refresh the cache.

I'm facing the a similar problem and restarting the domain doesn't seem to be working for me. I just thought I'd suggest it to you since it doesn't sound like you tried that.

Answer (score 0):

**Do the following steps**.

1. Undeploy all the applications deploy in the glassfish server.
2. Stop the glassfish server.
3. Clear the glassfish cache.(**Clear the following folders contents**)

   - $GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/*
   - $GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/osgi-cache/*
   - $GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/*
4. Now restart the glassfish server.